# Automatic intrinsic size for custom UIKit view inside SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I attempt to use a UIKit custom view named `LegalMentionView` (composed by 1 vertical stackview with 2 labels inside & 1 button) in my SwiftUI view.

So the stackview has a fixed width but no pre-defined height because labels are multilines.

I tried to play with Auto Layout constraintes but it didn't work.

The only way (bad I think) I found, is compute the height using `GeometryReader` with `Binding<CGFloat>` to pass value through the SwiftUI view.

Here the code:

```
@State private var legalMentionViewHeight: CGFloat = .zero

/// body
VStack {
    ...
    GeometryReader { reader in
        LegalMentionViewWrapped(
            desiredWidth: reader.size.width, // read full available width
            viewModel: legalMentionViewModel,
            computedHeight: $legalMentionViewHeight) // pass `legalMentionViewHeight` as binding
    }
    .frame(height: legalMentionViewHeight) // set frame height on `legalMentionViewHeight` changes
    ...
}

/// Wrapper
final class LegalMentionViewWrapped: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    public init(desiredWidth: CGFloat, viewModel: LegalMentionViewModel, computedHeight: Binding<CGFloat>) {
        self.desiredWidth = desiredWidth
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        _computedHeight = computedHeight
    }
    
    /// The desired width helping to compute its intrinsic size
    private var desiredWidth: CGFloat
    
    private var viewModel: LegalMentionViewModel
    
    /// Binding computed height used for the SwiftUI view
    @Binding private var computedHeight: CGFloat
    
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some LegalMentionView {
        return LegalMentionView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
    public func updateUIView(_ legalMentionView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        legalMentionView.viewModel = viewModel
        
        computeIntrisicSize(legalMentionView)
    }

    private func computeIntrisicSize(_ view: LegalMentionView) {
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height)
        let fittingSize = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize,
                                                       withHorizontalFittingPriority: .defaultHigh,
                                                       verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
            
        computedHeight = fittingSize.height
    }
}
```

Is somebody has a better idea to get the proper height more dynamically / without weird computation?

Comment: Not really sure what do you try to achieve. In majority of cases it is not needed any calculations at all for representable (if their own internal only! layout is correct)

Comment: When I don't use GeometryReader and binding computedHeight, the intrinsic size of my UIKit custom view is always 0. This is why, for now, I need calculations.